# Cannot get DVD drives to work on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: mount, dell

I Just loaded Ubuntu 17.10 on an old Dell Windows XP computer and cannot get my DVD drives to work. I ran

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom
```

I got  mount point does not exist.

Comment: Which model of Dell? Do you mean before had Windows XP? Could you provide the output of `lsblk -f`, `sudo lshw -class disk` and `ls -lah /dev/ | egrep "cdrom|dvd"`?

Comment: I am running a Dell XPL 400 from bought January 2006.  Yes it used to run XP.

Comment: lsblk -f 
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
fd0                                                      
sda                                                      
└─sda1 ext4         1aa8ab97-9cb0-4987-a09a-f8572c793f1b /
sr0                                                      
sr1

Comment: lsblk -f , sudo lshw -class disk
lsblk: invalid option -- 'c'

Comment: total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root        4.2K Jan 31 17:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root        4.0K Jan 29 17:09 ..
crw-------   1 root root     10, 235 Jan 31 17:40 autofs
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root         380 Jan 31 17:40 block
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root         180 Jan 31 17:40 bsg
crw-------   1 root root     10, 234 Jan 31 17:40 btrfs-control
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root          60 Jan 31 17:40 bus
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root           3 Jan 31 17:40 cdrom -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root           3 Jan 31 17:40 cdrw -> sr1
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root        4.0K Jan 31 17:40 char

Comment: The actual output is 11, 700 character longer and too long to post.

Comment: What I meant was you to edit the question, adding all that extra info  (the output of those commands) . [You can use Markdown](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)! As you might notice its not possible to show properly the output of commands here on comments.

Answer (score 2):

Create the mount point by running `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom`, then retry.

Comment: This would be more of a comment or question to be added to the comment. Its not an answer ... has he checked to see if there is a `/mnt/cdrom` directory? maybe it exists already so your "answer" doesn't answer the question... it's a suggestion about something he can check.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/801324)

Comment: Different answers here can contain various different solutions to the problem presented. This is one solution to the problem presented that works in most cases. This is a full solution to the problem in the cases where it works, so it's not just something to do solely diagnostically. It constitutes a standalone answer to the problem presented.

Comment: This is what I get:     mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/cdrom’: Permission denied

Comment: @JRAgua Did you do it with `sudo` on the front, like in the text above?

Comment: No, you are right.  I reran it with sudo in front and it asked form my password and apparently created the directory.   Now I tried to get VLC to play the DVD and the DVD spins and apparently is being read (makes that sound) but nothing happens on the screen.

Comment: This is error message from VLC:  Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/sr0".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details.
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).

Comment: @JRAgua This is a different problem than mounting `/dev/sr0` to `/mnt/cdrom` (which is unnecessary in the first place with VLC) and getting the error message about a missing mount point. Please ask a new question, including whether you mounted the DVD to `/mnt/cdrom` before the problem arose or not.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is put a disk into the tray so it can show a file size.

Do `lsblk` and find the disk with around 1 to 4 gigs.

Make sure it has a mounting point so do `sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom`

Then do `sudo mount /dev/(NAME OF DRIVE) /mnt/cdrom`

**Adding it to boot**

Do `sudo nano -w /etc/fstab`

Add the line

`/dev/(NAME OF DRIVE HERE) /cdrom iso9660 ro,noauto 0 0` and add the name

**Simple testing**

Just do `eject` to open and `eject -t` to close to prove that its even connected

Comment: Yes, it ejects and closes with those commands.

Comment: Here are results of first and third commands:    lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1     4K  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 232.8G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1   4.2G  0 rom  /media/jrafael/FIRST_SERIES
sr1     11:1    1     2K  0 rom ;  sudo /dev/ media/jrafael/FIRST_SERIES/mnt/cdrom
sudo: /dev/: command not found